# Add row to SQL array

Tags: mysql

Sorry to have to ask this, but I have searched and searched and can't seem to figure out how to do this...

I have this code on a custom PHP page:

```
(code placeholder spot which I will reference later)

$races = $wpdb->get_results("
      select r.race_name
            ,r.race_id
            ,date_format(r.race_date,'%c.%d.%Y') race_date
        from race_calendar r
       order by r.race_date;
      ");

foreach ( $races as $race ) {
  echo $race->race_id . ',' . $race->race_name . ',' . $race->race_date;
}
```

Which displays something like this:

```
1, Resolution, 2017-01-17
2, Sea 2 Sea, 2017-03-02
3, Earth Day, 2017-04-22
```

But, here's my question...

I need to be able to add a custom row at the beginning of the array.

So, I need to be able to add some code at the exact place above where I have **(code placeholder spot which I will reference later)** which will insert anything I want as the first row of the array.

I want to be able add a custom row, for example, "id, name, date" so that when I run the display code it will display this:

```
id, name, date
1, Resolution, 2017-01-17
2, Sea 2 Sea, 2017-03-02
3, Earth Day, 2017-04-22
```

I've tried a few things I've found online but nothing seems to work.

And no, a simple 'echo' command won't do. I don't want to go into details why (because it will make this post very long), but in my case I need the custom row added to the array.

Please help!

=================== EDIT (ANSWERED!!) ======================

Thanks to @Abdul I got it to work with this code:

```
$races_to_send =  array(array ('name', 'id', 'date'));

$races = $wpdb->get_results("
        select r.race_name
              ,r.race_id
              ,date_format(r.race_date,'%c.%d.%Y') race_date
         from race_calendar r
        order by r.race_name
                ,r.race_date;
       ", ARRAY_N);

$merged_arr = array_merge($races_to_send, $races);

foreach ( $merged_arr as $race ) {
      echo $race['0'] . ',' . $race['1'] . ',' . $race['2'];
    }
```

Comment: Hello @mannyotr - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! As your question stands it may be considered "off-topic" - while it occurs in the *context* of WordPress, it's not actually a question *about* WordPress or WordPress development. Rather, your question shows a lack of basic PHP knowledge (and thus research effort). Achieving your desired outcome does not require altering the database or inserting rows into results - just place your text in an `echo()` function call before the `foreach` loop, i.e. `echo("here are some values")`. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help].

Comment: `echo "here are some values";`? This looks like a basic PHP question

Comment: I don't want to go into the detail of why, but I can't use an echo command. The custom row has to be inserted into the array. If you really need the details I will provide them, but an echo command will not work in my case.

Comment: The text you are trying to insert does fit the format of one of your "races" - thus it is illogical to insert it into an array of races, and attempt to print it to the screen as though it were a race. Breaking separation of concerns in such a manner would make your code needlessly complex. If you can't use an `echo()` for some reason, then just close out the PHP tag before the content, write it verbatim, then open the PHP tag once more. `?> here are some values <br> <?php foreach( //...`

Comment: @bosco, I have modified my question. Assume the row I want to insert does fit the format. For example, the new row would be `id, name, date`. How then could I add the row to the array?

Comment: Well, `$races` should just be an array of objects... I imagine you could just unshift your custom object onto the beginning of the array before the `foreach` loop. `array_unshift( $races, array( 'race_id' => 'id', 'race_name' => 'name', 'race_date' => 'date' ) );`

Comment: As an afterthought, you might have to cast your custom array as an object in order to keep using object operator (i.e. `->`) in your `foreach` loop. So something like `array_unshift( $races, (object) $race_headers );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
$custom_row = array(array('race_id' => '1', 'race_name' => '2', 'race_date' => '3'));

$races = $wpdb->get_results("
      select r.race_name
            ,r.race_id
            ,date_format(r.race_date,'%c.%d.%Y') race_date
        from race_calendar r
       order by r.race_date;
      ", ARRAY_N);
$merged_arr = array_merge($custom_row, $races);
foreach ( $merged_arr as $race ) {
  echo $race['race_id'] . ',' . $race['race_name'] . ',' . $race['race_date'];
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
$custom_row = array(array('1', '2', '3'));

$races = $wpdb->get_results("
      select r.race_name
            ,r.race_id
            ,date_format(r.race_date,'%c.%d.%Y') race_date
        from race_calendar r
       order by r.race_date;
      ", ARRAY_N);
$merged_arr = array_merge($custom_row, $races);
foreach ( $merged_arr as $race ) {
  echo $race['0'] . ',' . $race['1'] . ',' . $race['2'];
}
```

Comment: I had already tried that. When I did the first row displayed simply contained `()` and nothing else, followed by the rest of the rows as expected.

Comment: Looks like you've used a modified version of this code. Try using exact same code. specially  `ARRAY_N` is important here

Comment: I have modified my original post to explain why that didn't work.

Comment: Have you used the same code I've provided ?

Comment: Yes, the exact code you provided is what I used on my EDIT 03.

Comment: Thats weird! Can you do var_dump for $merged_arr and show me the output ?

Comment: See EDIT 04 in my original post above.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the answer with updated code, That should work, Please try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55820/discussion-between-mannyotr-and-abdul-awal).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved the problem you should try to use numeric array in case of your race_to_add. It should help to return correct array for printing function